# How to derive the heat equation from the laws of thermodynamic?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Does anyone know how to derive the following one-dimensional heat equation from the laws of thermodynamic?

$\rho\ c \frac{\partial\ T}{\partial\ t} - div(\kappa\ \frac{\partial\ T}{\partial\ x}) = \dot{q}_v$

Comment: You can easily google this.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a lot with the problem. It seems that all I have to do is to formulate the potential form of the heat equation in such a way that the derivative of the potential with respect to the variable yield the weak form of the equilibrium.